# MAX232 and bluetooth module HC-10, error receiving

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port

I'm quite new at Bluetooth and MAX232. We have Machines at work that are controlled by RS-232 (9-PIN) at the moment and I've managed to create a program that talks to the machine through RS-232.

But then I had this brilliant idea that I could add a HC-10 module to the MAX232 which I did and the machine responds to the commands but here the weird part that I cannot find anything about:

1. When connected to RS-232 (9-PIN), in idle state the Machines send Three separate commands to let me know the status (144, 1, 245) over and over again.
2. But when connected via Bluetooth I only receive one command from the unit in idle state: 211 over and over again.

I know that the RX and TX works because I can both recieve and transmit data but why do I only get one instead of three commands from the unit in idle state? Is there something I'm missing?

Is the BT slower than RS-232 (9-PIN) and the machine needs to delay between sending the idle commands?

Answer (score 0):

I had time to sit down with the devices and also studied the MAX232 chip. The first problem was that I had connected the RX/TX from the BT to 13 & 14 when it should have been 11 & 12. I do not know if this solved anything, i Think it's same tho.

The second problem was that instead of Three rows from the BT it gathered all information to one line (multiple characters). So when I iterated the Array (3 characters) and converted the character to decimal I got 144, 1, 245.

Thats why I received 211 because the string had Three characters that I tried to convert to decimal instead of one.
Hope this will help anyone :)